# openapi-generator generates empty interface

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am trying to generate TS stubs for the API of the backend services. My problem is that it generates an empty interface which I cannot use in my TypeScript code...

**Here is the spec:**

```json
{
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Schema1": {
        "properties": {
          "metric": {
            "type": "array"
          }
        }
      },
      "Schema2": {
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "string"
              }
            ],
            "title": "Address"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "info": {
    "title": "Test API",
    "version": "v1.11.1"
  },
  "openapi": "3.1.0"
}
```

**Here is the command-line:**

```
java -jar 7.1.0.jar generate --input-spec=api.json --generator-name="typescript-fetch" --output="tmp/"
```

And **the interfaces produced** (combining two files here and extracting only the relevant stuff):

```js
export interface Address {
}

export interface Schema2 {
    address?: Address;
}
```

`Address` is supposed to be a string, here it is mapped to an empty interface.
Oddly enough, if I remove Schema1 from the spec, the code generated is correct:

```
export interface Schema2 {
    address?: string;
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you using *anyOf* but with only one option? What happens if you just set the type of address directly to string?

Comment: The `anyOf` was there because the type was nullable. But removing it now generates `address?: any | null;` which is not better since all type information is gone, and the `null` makes no sense. Adding another `{"type": "integer"}` to the `anyOf` generates the same empty interface.

Answer (score 0):

As specified [in the swagger spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/), the items keyword is required in arrays, and my spec didn't have any. As a matter of fact, the generation always displayed an exception, and I didn't think it was related:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.get$ref()" because the return value of "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.getItems()" is null
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPINormalizer.processNormalize31Spec(OpenAPINormalizer.java:902)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPINormalizer.normalizeSimpleSchema(OpenAPINormalizer.java:446)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPINormalizer.normalizeSchema(OpenAPINormalizer.java:437)
...
```

Typing the array in `Schema1` fixes the issue, and the exception is not thrown anymore when generating the stubs:

```
{
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Schema1": {
        "properties": {
          "metric": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"  
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Schema2": {
        "properties": {
          "address": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "info": {
    "title": "Test API",
    "version": "v1.11.1"
  },
  "openapi": "3.1.0"
}
```